# How do I model a many-to-many relation in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to introduce a many-to-many relationship between two tables, which both have an integer for primary key, in a SQL Server database. How is this best done in T-SQL?

Consider the following two example table definitions for which there should be a many-to-many relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Authors] (
    [Id]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Versions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Books] (
    [Id]      INT           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The traditional way is to use an additional `many:many` (junction) table, which links to both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuthorsBooks] (
    -- Optionally, we can give the table its own surrogate PK
    [Id]      INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    AuthorId INT NOT NULL,
    BookId INT NOT NULL,

    -- Referential Integrity
    FOREIGN KEY(AuthorId) REFERENCES Authors(Id),
    FOREIGN KEY(BookId) REFERENCES Books(Id),

    -- PK is either the surrogate ...
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
    -- ... Or the compound key
    -- PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (AuthorId, BookId)
);
```

One moot point is whether you want the compound key `AuthorId, BookId` to be the Primary Key, or whether to add your own new Surrogate - this is usually a subjective preference.

Some of the points to consider whether going for a compound primary key or a new surrogate key for the Junction table:

- Without the surrogate, external tables linking to the junction table would need to store both compound keys (i.e. would need to retain both `AuthorId` and `BookId` as foreign keys).
- So a new surrogate offers the potential benefit of a narrower primary key, which then means any tables linking to this junction table will have a single, narrower foreign key.
- However, with the compound keys, there can be an optimisation benefit that tables can join directly to the underlying `Books` or `Authors` tables without first joining to the junction table.

The following diagram hopefully makes the case of the compound key clearer (the middle table `Nationality` is a junction table of `PersonCountry`):

[image: Composite Foreign Key]

**Edit**

Usage is straightforward - if the link exists in the many:many table, then the relationship is deemed to exist. To test the existence, you 'join through' the link table e.g.

```
-- Find all books written by AuthorId 1234
SELECT b.* 
  FROM Books b 
  INNER JOIN AuthorsBooks ab
     ON b.Id = ab.BookId
  WHERE ab.AuthorId = 1234;
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured I'd go for the composite Primary Key approach, do you mind documenting how to implement this as well?

Comment: Shouldn't `FOREIGN KEY(AuthorId) REFERENCES Authors(AuthorId)` be `FOREIGN KEY(AuthorId) REFERENCES Authors(Id)` instead, as you're referring to the column name in the foreign table? Same goes for the BookId foreign key. That's the error I get when writing the T-SQL script in Visual Studio at least.

Comment: @aknuds1 - yes, you are absolutely correct. Our naming standard is [TableName]Id.